# OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, url, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I have two different A and B web applications hosted on tomcat. The B application is hosted on 4 physical systems with separate tomcat. And application A is hosted on 5th physical system with separate tomcat. Whenever login/logout event happens on application A, it needs to send this notification to all 4 B applications. Application A creates the one thread for each event, and this thread make the request to all 4 B applications using following code:

```
public class SendNotification implements Runnable {
  private String action;
  private String loginid;
  private Thread thread;
  StringBuilder sb  =     new StringBuilder();

  public static SendNotification getInstance() {
        return new SendNotification();
  }
  public void sendNotification(String action, String loginid){
        this.action = action;
        this.loginid = loginid;
        sb.append(loginid)
        .append("_")
        .append(action)
        .append(new Date().getTime());
        thread = new Thread(this, sb.toString());
        thread.start();
  }

  public void run(){
        String methodName =     "run";
        int   len = 4;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
              synchronized(this){
                    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder()
                    .append(<Server_B_i_IP:PORT>)
                    .append("&action=").append(action)
                    .append("&loginid=").append(loginid);
                    URL urlObj                    =     null;
                    InputStream openStream  =     null;
                    try {
                          urlObj = new URL(url.toString());
                          openStream = urlObj.openStream();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                          ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                          try {
                                if(openStream != null){
                                      openStream.close();
                                }
                                openStream  =     null;
                                urlObj            =     null;
                                url               =     null;
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                    }
              }           
        }
        destroyObject();
  }

  private void destroyObject() {
        thread      =     null;
  }
```

}

But after some time tomcat start throwing following exception:

```
Exception in thread "qe01lj_login_success1320054407929" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
                at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:574)
                at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:836)
                at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1030)
                at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1057)
                at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1041)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:402)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:917)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
                at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
                at com.test. sendNotification.run(sendNotification.java:69)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

How can I resolve above issue?

These applications are running HTTPS on Tomcat 5.5.17 with jdk1.5.0_13

Answer (score 4):

> How can I resolve above issue?

The immediate cause of the problem is that you are running out of memory to create new threads.  (This memory doesn't come out of the normal heap, so changing `-Xmx` won't help.)

The actual cause is that threads are being created faster than they are exiting.  I *suspect* that this statement is the root of the problem:

```
synchronized (this) {
    // talk to network ...
}
```

The problem is that `this` will be the instance of `SendNotification` that you used to send the notification.  If you reuse that object, you will find that you have a serious bottleneck that is causing the network tasks to be performed one at a time.

In addition to the issue above, your approach is flawed because each time you call `sendNotification`, it overwrites the state of the `SendNotification` instance without any synchronization.  Simply, you should not be using a singleton to hold state for a number of threads ...

---

The other possibility is that you are not reusing the `SendNotification` instances, and (therefore) the synchronization issues aren't the cause of the problem.  In that case, the next possible cause is that you are simply creating new threads faster than the server can process them.

The immediate solution is to use a bounded thread pool so that you never have more than (say) 20 threads active at a time.  There are standard classes for doing this kind of thing.

However, there going to be a limit on the rate at which your application / platform can perform these tasks.  If you exceed that limit over an extended period your application's queues will build up and you will run into trouble.  If this is likely, then your application needs some kind of strategy for shedding load.

---

Hmmm ...

The SSL stack appears to be creating a thread to perform the SSL negotiation in the background.  You appear to be opening a connection to the remote server and then closing it immediately ... without reading anything.  Maybe this unusual usage pattern causes the SSL negotiation thread to leak.  Try reading a byte from the stream before you close it.  That is likely to cause the current thread to `join` the SSL negotiation thread and it won't be left in limbo.

If this is what is happening, then it is probably a bug in the Java SSLSocketImpl code you are using.  You should upgrade the JVM and Tomcat to get the latest (and not-so-latest!) security, performance and bug fixes.  It may not fix this problem ... but you should do it anyway.

**UPDATE** - Googling for "SSLSocketImpl bug leak" gives a lot of hits.  I didn't spot one that exactly matches, but an upgrade is advisable nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your prompt reply. if you look at the getInstance() method, it creates the new object of SendNotification class. Therefore it is not a singleton class. 
What if I removes the synchronized block? Will this resolve the issue?

Comment: Each instance of SendNotification class creates the new Thread, and this thread makes the request to all 4 B application using openStream() method of URL class.
So my question is, does openStream() method creates the new thread for communicating with application B?
If we look at the Exception StackTrace, it is showing 
unable to create new native thread at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:574)

Comment: So for every request there are 5 thread get created? (one by SendNotification class and 4 by openStream() method)?

If yes, then if application A gets 100 login request simultaneously then it will create 500 threads at a time.
Following are tomcat connector port configuration: 

<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="500" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\test.keystore" keystorePass="aaaaa" />

Comment: When application A crashed at that time, the task manager was showing 1029 threads for tomcat5.exe process.

Comment: Use of a ThreadPoolExecutor with bonded queue is apt here. With this small change, you will abstract out your business logic from Thread management. The reason at the first sight of it looks like the creation of thread is faster than its destruction.

Comment: @TusharTarkas - you are correct that use of those classes is appropriate.  But I don't think that is going to solve the OP's problem.  See the last section of my answer.  (Starting with "Hmmm ...")