# Sprint Boot Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread, at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

It's more like to this problem : ["java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789288/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread, at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method), at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.startThread(QueuedThreadPool.java:660), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.ensureThreads(QueuedThreadPool.java:642), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStart(QueuedThreadPool.java:182), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169), at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:408), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117), at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97), at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372), at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72), at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:136), ... 22 more]","threadname":"main"},"time":"2022-01-19T07:39:47.295Z","timezone":"UTC","type":"log"}

Comment: There is far too little information here to be able to answer this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962528/outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40386639)